# GAE Soft private memory limit error on post requests

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, xml-parsing

I am working on an application where I am using the paid services of Google app engine. In the application I am parsing a large xml file and trying to extracting data to the datastore.  But while performing this task GAE is throwing me an error as below.
I also tried to change the performance setting by increasing frontend instance class from F1 to F2.

ERROR:
Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 133 MB after  servicing 14 requests total.
After handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

When you face the `Exceeded soft private memory limit` error you have two alternatives to follow:

1. To upgrade your instance to a [more powerful](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings) one, which gives you more memory.
2. To reduce the chunks of data you process in each request. You could split the XML file to smaller pieces and keep the smaller instance doing the work.

Comment: Please, how do you upgrade the Instance class on the Google Cloud Console?

Comment: For AppEngine apps, you cannot do it from the console, you'll need to change it on your app.yaml and re-deploy. Most probably, just like you've done when increasing from F1 to F2

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mario's answer.  Your options are indeed to either upgrade to an [Instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/about-the-standard-environment#instance_classes) with more memory such as F2 or F3 or process these XML files in smaller chunks.

To help you decide what would be the best path for this task, you would need to know if these XML files to be processed will grow in size.  If the XML file(s) will remain approximately this size, you can likely just upgrade the instance class for a quick fix.

If the files ***can*** grow in size, then augmenting the instance memory may only buy you more time before encountering this limit again.  In this case, your ideal option would be to use a stream to parse the XML file(s) in smaller units, consuming less memory.  In Python, [xml.sax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.html) can be used to accomplish just that as the `parse` method can accept streams.  You would need to implement your own [`ContentHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.handler.html#contenthandler-objects) methods.

In your case, the file is coming from the POST request but if the file were coming from Cloud Storage, you should be able to use the [client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#open) to stream the content through to the parser.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, almost sure it's my usage of `/tmp` directory was causing it, this directory is mounted in memory which was causing it. So, if you are writing any files into `/tmp` don't forget to remove them!

Another option is that you actully have a memory leak! It says `after servicing 14 requests` - this means the getting more powerful instance will only delay the error. I would recommend cleaning memory, now I don't know what your code looks like, I'm trying following with my code:

```py
import gc

# ...

@app.route('/fetch_data')
def fetch_data():
    data_object = fetch_data_from_db()
    uploader = AnotherHeavyObject()

    # ...
    response = extract_data(data_object)


    del data_object
    del uploader
    gc.collect()

    return response
```

After trying things above, now it seems that issue was with `FuturesSession` - related to this `https://github.com/ross/requests-futures/issues/20`. So perhaps it's another library you're using - but just be warned that some of those libraries leak memory - and AppEngine preserves state - so whatever is not cleaned out - stays in memory, and affects following requests on that same instance.