# Google App Engine "Exceeded soft memory limit on "

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

We have a long-time running service on Google App Engine(GAE). However, after a while, we began to get the error in the image. No changes to the code. I don't understand why we're having the problem we didn't have before.

> 2020-01-05 08:31:32.704 UTC-8
> Exceeded soft memory limit of 2048 MB with 2068 MB after servicing 0 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.
>
> 2020-01-05 08:31:32.705 UTC-8
> This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
>
> 2020-01-05 08:31:32.705 UTC-8
> The warmup request failed. Please check your warmup handler implementation and make sure it's working correctly.

[image: Error image]

**Edit: System Info;**

We are running python.
I have cronjobs.

Comment: This means that there's a memory leak happening. Can you tell me a bit more about the systems you are using? Are you running Java/Python? If you are using ndb, loading quite a lot of entities in a single query fetch will cause the memory limit to exceed. Or you might be loading quite some chunks of data from a third party system. (Keeping all the data loaded in memory).

Comment: We are running python. Actually, I checked to see if there was too much data loading. I deleted the cache of the data taken from the database. I even set up another new service in a different structure. The same error always occurs. I can't find the source of this error that doesn't normally come. Could it be due to a new operation of Google? @yaswanth

Comment: @sumeyye as yaswanth said, it's a memory issue, you probably have a memory leak somewhere, not related to google. Carefully review your application with a profiler, check memory usage and try to understand what you can do to fix it or if you need an instance with bigger memory

Comment: If you are using the "inbound_service: warmup" try remove it

Answer (score 2):

Do you know, how much memory it consumes when you run it locally?

With [Stackdriver Profiler](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/) which is in beta, you can find what's happening with your memory usage.

When there is the Exceeded soft private memory limit error, you can follow two alternatives:

1) You can upgrade your instance to an another with more [memory](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes)

2) You can reduce the chunks of data you process in each request, process the  XML file in smaller pieces and keep the smaller instance doing the work.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704555/gae-soft-private-memory-limit-error-on-post-requests) is a similar post which can help.

Answer (score 2):

[memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMW2h.png)

I am experiencing the same increasing memory (memory leak?) issue on GAE standard evironment, python3 + flask on projects that were running for years without any problem. I also tried instances with higher memory, but that was not a solution.

Switch from requests_futures library with requests and explicity set `entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 -w 1 main:app` solved issue to me in one of the project.

Seems that on python2 these problems do not occur.

Comment: Actually, we solved this problem by switching to kubernetes. We really started to have troubles in Google-App-Engine. Instead of wasting time on it, it was smarter to switch to kubernetes. @janq

Comment: On my projects it only occurs when using python 3.

Comment: Only workaround working to me is to restart gunicorn worker after N requests `entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 -w 2 --max-requests=500 main:app`

Comment: @sumeyye I'm curious as to how kubernetes resolved this? Surely it doesn't allow for an application to just continue using more memory over time? Or do you think it resolved memory leaks in the underlying app engine platform?

Comment: @Mark thought I was answering. Sorry for the delay in response.  In fact, we have dealt with the app engine problem. We should not have a problem as a memory. At this point it took our time to meet with such an error. Currently, we run our containers in kubernetes with less memory than the memory in app-engine.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `instance_class` from `app.yaml` file. Which will increase the memory limit according to the assigned class. Refer to below link:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#instance_classes

Answer (score 0):

This is to turn the valuable comment by janq on the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60024436/7733418 into an answer of its own:

> Only workaround working to me is to restart gunicorn worker after N
> requests entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 -w 2 --max-requests=500
> main:app

We also used the -w 1 setting as suggested in the answer itself, because we already had concurrent requests disabled for other reasons:

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app -w 1 --max-requests=500
```

The difference in total memory usage was huge after deploying this - it is now around 40% of what it was before, with no other change. I don't see any repercussions from workers restarting. This should be in Google's documentation!