# API fails to load in GAE with a critical error suggesting memory leakage

Tags: google-app-engine, memory-leaks, google-cloud-storage, autoscaling

I have a pretty simple api that works loads some properties, enriches them and uploads them as a pdf blob in google store. It works perfectly fine on my local machine but fails with `"Exceeded soft memory limit of 512 MB with 630 MB after servicing 1 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml"` error on google cloud app engine.

Detailed logs:

```
While handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application or may be using an instance with insufficient memory. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.
```

I tried adding scaling attributes to app.yml as per the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#automatic_scaling but that doesnt seem to help.

```
manual_scaling:
 instances: 5
```

Any pointers on what might be the issue here?

Comment: The issue is clear.  Your PDF generation is exceeding memory limits.  You need to increase the memory of your instance or change your code to use less memory.  Adding more instances won't help.  You need more memory on each instance.

Comment: Hi @u009988 could you please check if the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25704555/gae-soft-private-memory-limit-error-on-post-requests) help you fix your issue? I believe there are some alternatives there, for you to avoid the memory issue.

Comment: Apparently, the solution is switching to a flexible environment according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57469842/how-to-increase-the-soft-memory-limit-for-google-app-engine-beyond-2gb/57470956#57470956)